# How to include language segment in the URL for links in Cake 3.0

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I need to build a multi-lingual site with the language in the url like this http://example.org/jp/users/login, but I want to avoid having to code the language into every link on the site. I effectively have this for routing:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:lang/:controller/:action/*',
    ['prefix' => 'customer'],
    ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute', 'lang' => '[a-z]{2}']
);
```

And I have to do this for links:

```
$this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['lang' => 'en', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Is there any way so that lang can be added automatically and I can just do this for links instead?

```
$this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `'persist' => ['lang']` to options array of your `$routes->connect()` statement.

Comment: You can try using my [i18n](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-i18n) plugin which provides custom route class to simplify connecting routes with language prefix/fragment.